# Phonegap - App does not start

Tags: cordova

I'm currently developing a simple app with phonegap and js/html/css. Unfortunately, the app does not start on my Samsung Galaxy Ace 2. The splashscreen is displayed, but then the phone returns to the main menu.
I connected the device with my pc and copied the output of error messages from LogCat of eclipse:

```
04-02 00:11:09.788: E/ENSWrapper(1666): return OMX_ErrorNotImplemented - GetExtensionIndex OMX.ST.AFM.pcmprocessing.spl h=0x427cff68  cParameterName=STE.ADM IndexType=unknown OMX_INDEXTYPE [ 0x392e800e ]

04-02 00:11:13.052: A/libc(24830): @@@ ABORTING: HEAP MEMORY CORRUPTION IN tmalloc_large addr=0x5e88e048
04-02 00:11:13.052: A/libc(24830): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 24845 (WebViewCoreThre)

04-02 00:11:13.392: E/Watchdog(1995): !@Sync 1598

04-02 00:11:20.879: E/Dumper(1666): 6: 48148381244: User action: dump logging circular buffer and context
04-02 00:11:20.879: E/Dumper(1666): 7: 48148381305: Triggering circular buffer dump in /data/ste-debug
04-02 00:11:21.159: E/InputDispatcher(1995): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-02 00:11:21.250: E/Launcher(5707): Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_enabled
```

I have absolutely no idea what these things mean. "Heap memory corruption" does not sound good anyway.

Could you please help me here?

EDIT:

I found out that the app crashes or freezes as soon as the content area exceeds the visible area of my mobile phone.

Comment: Very likely yet another WebView bug. Can you try your app in the default browser and see if it crashes too?

Comment: I've recently switched to [CrossWalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) from Cordova; it comes with it's own embedded chromium that is light years ahead of WebView - might work for you as well.

Comment: Do you have a lot of code launched directly in the js or at deviceReady? I used to have some hangs long time ago and solved it by adding setTimeout of 100ms in deviceReady before strarting to process the view.

Comment: which plugins have you added to your project and do you use the media player?

Comment: Can you share your app source code on github or somewhere so that i can test it on my side?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Eclipse** > **Preferences**

[image]

**General** > Tick **Show heap status**

[image]

Then clean your heap size at the bottom of your eclipse. (rubbish icon)

[image]

If it still happen, please follow step by step from this site.

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/03/15/your-eclipse-always-crash-how-to-fix-and-enhance-to-do-list/

Comment: Thanks but it is not my eclipse that crashes, but my app.

Comment: Tried that but it still does not work. The app had crashed before I installed eclipse - ADT anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in your firmware.

- Try running on Simulator or any other Nexus devices.

Also can be issue because of heavy images used.

- Try reducing the size of images or size of HTML/CSS